# Domain name A record not getting update

Tags: dns

I had my domain setup on a friends server until recently, but now I'm moving out from his VPS and would like to host the site on Posterous/Tumblr. Both these blogs ask for a A record to be update with my domain registrar and although I did that, the domain seems to be pointing to the old name servers. The problem for that seems the name servers which I was using for the previous VPS hosting is still present and I'm unable to remove it. On asking the domain register support they replied saying that

> As per registry rules you require to provide any two valid NS, we cannot keep value as blank.

I'm in a fix of wasting my domain as I would not want to use it anywhere else. Any help would be appreciated.

The domain is http://reversepolartiy.in

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just update/add the A record on the old name servers?

Comment: i Did add a new A record but the old name servers seem to be having effect and the A record seems to not work.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. If the OLD nameservers are authoritative for the domain, they will need to have an A record for the domain

Answer (score 2):

Like the previous poster mentioned, the NS are not returning the correct information for your TLD. "A" records and NS records are not the same thing, you need to update the NS under your DNS management (usually but not always under the control panel for your domain provider) to point to the new provider.

The A record would then point to the IP address of the new provider.